# Stay Zoom in mobile chrome whenever touched on ChatBox

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat, google-chrome

While using the mobile Chrome browser for browsing the chat sites it repeatedly zoom in even after I zoom out by using the pinch gesture. While in zoom mode the full site look weird.

Normal State after zoom out

[image]

As I tap on ChatBox it automatically gets zoomed in and then remains zoomed

[image]

I can't even click on the send button without zooming out. The issue re-happens whenever I tap or touch the ChatBox.

It happens on [Chat on MSE](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/) as well as on [Chat on SO](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Oh, this... fear it's a browser feature. You can still submit the message by pressing the ENTER key.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yup thanks that worked. but can't we fixed zooming issue or functionality?

Comment: Well, that's not SE's fault and I doubt Google will change this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We aren't doing any special zooming. Mobile browsers for some reason like to, though.

I agree that it's a pain, but the best I can offer here is to use the mobile chat view instead of the full desktop mode.

Comment: In mobile chat view i cant reply to particular message and can't see/read removed messages too. :(

Comment: Mobile chat view lack all features, you can only read messages and write messages. No stars. No replying. Nada. Gave up on using it long ago. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't disagree.